# MS Visio diagram showing intraction with a message queue

Tags: diagram, visio

Sorry for a silly question.

I need to draw a diagram in MS Visio showing how some small piece of C++ code works. There are two threads: the main GUI thread that renders some data (represented with some object model) with DirectX, and the data receiver thread that queues some messages received over TCP. GUI thread processes all the messages in the queue after each flip (emptying the queue) and makes corresponding changes to the data model.

What kind of diagram should I use to depict this process? Primarily I need to show processing messages from the message queue and changes made to the data model, but not structure of the data model and not objects and classes it consist of.